# Combine rows + Groupby/apply function

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, apply

I have dataframe as follows (dataframe1):

```
    ID  Group   Start   End
0   ID1   A       1      2
1   ID1   A       2      3
2   ID1   A       3      4
3   ID1   B       4      5
4   ID1   B       5      6
5   ID2   A       6      7
6   ID2   A       7      8
7   ID2   B       8      9
8   ID2   B       9     10
9   ID2   B       11    12
```

I want to create new dataframe, where if for unique ID End value is equal to Start Value from another row, it should be combine into one row (IDs must be in same group).
So, I want sth like this (dataframe2):

```
    ID  Group   Start   End
0   ID1   A       1      4
3   ID1   B       4      6
5   ID2   A       6      8
7   ID2   B       8      10
9   ID2   B       11     12
```

It's too complicated for me now. So first of all I thought about sth with groupby and apply. I shifted End column by one (down direction) in each group and check how many times Start value is equal to end_shifted values (I can also use this in later analysis of dataset, so it's not that useless). So I've wrote function:

```
def mygroup(df):
    
    is_continued = 0
    
    df['End'] = df['End'].shift(1)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['Start'] == row['End']):
            is_continued = is_continued + 1
            
    return is_continued
```

and then:

```
is_continued = dataframe.groupby(['ID']).apply(mygroup)
```

I thought that it will give me 4 for ID1 and 4 for ID2, but not.

```
ID
ID1    4
ID2    0
dtype: int64
```

So my questions are.

1. What am I doing wrong with groupby/apply.
2. How can I combine these rows to get dataframe2?

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience with Pandas and as such (1) I can't answer your first question and (2) as far as your second question goes, this is probably not the way an expert would do it. But I offer it as a solution:

```
import pandas as pd


def combine_rows(df):
    id = []
    group = []
    start = []
    end = []
    prev_row = None
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if prev_row is None:
            prev_row = row
            prev_end = prev_row.End
            continue
        if row.ID == prev_row.ID and row.Group == prev_row.Group and row.Start == prev_end:
            prev_end = row.End
        else:
            id.append(prev_row.ID)
            group.append(prev_row.Group)
            start.append(prev_row.Start)
            end.append(prev_end)
            prev_row = row
            prev_end = prev_row.End
    if prev_row is not None:
        id.append(prev_row.ID)
        group.append(prev_row.Group)
        start.append(prev_row.Start)
        end.append(prev_end)
    return pd.DataFrame({"ID": id, "Group": group, "Start": start, "End": end})

        
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ['ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID2', 'ID2', 'ID2', 'ID2'],
    "Group": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    "Start": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11],
    "End": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
})
print(df)
df = combine_rows(df)
print(df))
```

Prints:

```
    ID Group  Start  End
0  ID1     A      1    2
1  ID1     A      2    3
2  ID1     A      3    4
3  ID1     B      4    5
4  ID1     B      5    6
5  ID2     A      6    7
6  ID2     A      7    8
7  ID2     B      8    9
8  ID2     B      9   10
9  ID2     B     11   12
    ID Group  Start  End
0  ID1     A      1    4
1  ID1     B      4    6
2  ID2     A      6    8
3  ID2     B      8   10
4  ID2     B     11   12
```